# Issues with MySQL Queries on certain hosting packages

Tags: php, mysql, html, hosting

I've been building a website on a subdomain of my companies hosting package. It's got PHP MySQL operations happening in the background, i.e. INSERTs, SELECTs etc.

They are the most basic of basic SQL statements and they all work fine.

However, I recently copied EVERYTHING from my subdomain and uploaded it all to my clients own hosting package run by [1&1](http://1and1.co.uk/) and now, my INSERT statements do not work. SELECTs, DELETE statements all work fine, but not my INSERTS.

I think it's one of two problems, either it's a permissions error on the new database or I have some glaring error in my code that my last database didn't seem to mind so much.

Here's my insert code:

```
<?php
include 'data.php';

$b_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['businessName']);
$b_town = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['placeName']);
$b_code = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['postCode']);
$latlng = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['latLong']);

mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Wrong Information");

mysql_select_db($db) or die("Wrong Database");

$newloc = preg_replace("/^.*\(([^)]*)\).*$/", '$1', $latlng);

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO reseller_addresses VALUES (NULL ,  '$b_name',  '$b_code',  '$b_town',  '$newloc');") or die ("Broken Query");

echo "<script>setTimeout(\"self.parent.location.reload(true);\", 1000);</script><font color=\"#fbf7d7\">$businessName Successfully Added to the Database</font>";

mysql_close();
?>
```

It's concerning adding a geographic location into a database from a google map/form setup.

Unfortunately I can't authorise a live preview because the administration area where the trouble is happening is secure.

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: I've passed the same files back and forth my web server and my clients and they all work on mine, but not my clients.

EDIT: I've explained the actual problem badly here, sorry. Basically, a new record is inserted into the database, but it's empty.

A print_r($_POST); reveals:

```
Array ( [businessName] => test [placeName] => test [postCode] => test [latLong] => (51.152495, -1.440411) [Submit] => Submit Place )
```

Which IS everything I've submitted

Comment: What doesn't work? What error messages to you get?

Comment: It sounds like your db user on the client's host only has access for "read" operations. But you should get a definitive error from MySQL on this.

Comment: Looks like a permission/configuration problem where you can do anything but INSERT.

Comment: instead of  or die ("Broken Query"); try doing or die(mysql_error()); and see what comes up, that should have some info regarding the issue.

Comment: I've edited my OP, I realised how badly I explained the problem. A record is inserted, but it's blank. So it must be an issue with the $_POST I'd guess?

Comment: Sounds like. Check out your request in firebug and make sure all the values are getting passed as youd expect. IF you have access to the httpd error log then you can use a `trigger_error(print_r($_POST, true), E_USER_NOTICE)` and log whats in post. If you dont have error log access then set it up to write to the filesystem and review that file.

Comment: I've done a print_r as kitsched suggested and all the values are being passed correctly.

Comment: but an echoing the string as $b_name; reveals an empty string. What's wrong with : $b_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['businessName']);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace the line that says

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ...") or die ("Broken Query");
```

with the following:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ...";
echo $query;
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
$warnings = mysql_query("SHOW WARNINGS");
if ( mysql_num_rows($warnings) ) {
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($warnings) ) {
        echo "\nMySQL Warning: ".$row['Message'];
    }
} else {
    echo "\nNo warnings";
}
```

and tell us what is output.

Also, please add `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT);` immediately after `include 'data.php';`
, and see if you get any error messages.

Please also give us the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE reseller_addresses`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but since I wrote the question I've discovered that the problem is not with my query but with my mysql_real_escape_string. Removing this makes the query work fine, however, on the flip side, how am I going to prevent attacks without this?

Comment: Are you certain that the problem is with `mysql_real_escape_string()`? Do the following: `$b_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['businessName']); echo "Before: ".$_POST['businessName']."\nAfter: ".$b_name;` and tell us what is output.

Comment: it's definitely mysql_real_escape_string(). Strange thing is, I've used this code as stock on a lot of my websites, but I've never had this trouble. God I hate 1&1

Comment: I have no experience of using the `mysql_` functions, as I've only ever used `mysqli_`. All I can suggest is changing to `mysqli_` and seeing if that fixes it. (Others may suggest using PDO instead, and that's good too, but may be considerably more refactoring work than just changing to `mysqli`, depending on the size and complexity of your codebase.)

Answer (score 0):

I did a series of tests and the problem lay with the mysql_real_escape_string line. I removed this and it worked. I still need some injection protection however, so I added in addslashes.

I have no idea why it acted in this way and I hope my fix wasn't temporary.